# как сделать чтобы доступ к регистрации в dokuwiki был только с одной (например главной) страницы

Tags: php, .htaccess

как сделать чтобы доступ к регистрации в dokuwiki был только с одной (например главной) страницы

Это понятно, что можно подправить шаблон и ссылка на регистрацию и вход  останется только с одной страницы)) Однако же в dokuwiki достаточно добавить к странице (к урл) ?do=register или соответственно   ?do=login и .. добро пожаловать ) А как ограничить этот доступ ? Сделать какую то хитрую переадресацию со страниц вида site.ru/stranica?do=register ?? Но как ? 
Мой вопрос о dokuwiki

Comment: Задача довольно нетривиальна вне зависимости где будет выполняться. потому что вы не можете даже достоверно узнать откуда что либо вызвано и не дописал ли пользователь сам параметры. Единственным действенным способом будет дописывать к валидным ссылкам некий специальный параметр именно там, где такая ссылка допустима. в параметре можно шифровать некую информацию о клиенте, вроде ip адреса и возможно текущего времени. При приходе пользователя на регистрацию надо проверять что этот параметр действительно выдавался именно этому клиенту.

Comment: Я понимаю) о том и вопрос. А нельзя ли все-таки  сделать переадресацию , например,  всех адресов, которые заканчиваются на  ?do=register куда в одно место?  А все остальное  понятно мне с самого начала, иначе бы вопрос не задавал )